# How to write in two columns like a table in Linux man pages?

Tags: manpage

I'm creating a custom man page for my C library, and I'd like to do a thing like this

```
LIST OF FUNCTIONS                            |<--- terminal window side
                                             |
Function        Description                  |
function1       function1's description      |
function2       function2's description      |
                which is longer than the     |<--- here if the text 
                first one                    | overlaps out of the window,
function3       function3's description      | it auto-aligns to Description
...             ...                          |
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's a combination of https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Man-Page/q3.html and then use GROFF - https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1158

```
.SH DESCRIPTION
.B foo
frobnicates the bar library by tweaking internal
symbol tables. By default it parses all baz segments
and rearranges them in reverse order by time for the
.BR xyzzy (1)
linker to find them. The symdef entry is then compressed
using the WBG (Whiz-Bang-Gizmo) algorithm.
All files are processed in the order specified.
```

There is a command on the linuxjournal site with the following:

```
$ groff -Tascii -man coffee.man | more
```

The groff man page starts with the following:

```
The man macro package for groff is used to produce manual pages
       (“man pages”) like the one you are reading.
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it displays everything in line like normal text

Comment: I've updated the post to show a command using the groff command usage

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to do it with just the basic man command

Comment: Reading the man page (no pun intended) for groff shows that it actually creates the man page for you - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_man.7.html